# ufw rules not properly working to access elasticsearch from outside from certain ips

Tags: ufw

I have the following rules in my ufw. What i want to allow is access to port 9200 (elasticsearch) from certain IPs. I obviously added some rules but I can't access es from outside with the added IP if ufw is enabled. Is there some mistake in the config?

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9020                       DENY IN     Anywhere
9200                       DENY IN     Anywhere
5606                       DENY IN     Anywhere
8015                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9300                       ALLOW IN    94.130.132.23
9200                       ALLOW IN    94.130.132.23
9200/tcp                   ALLOW IN    94.130.132.23
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9020 (v6)                  DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
9200 (v6)                  DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
5606 (v6)                  DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
8015 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Could you provide the command that you issued?

Comment: sudo ufw allow from 94.130.132.23 to any port 9200